# Connection of SQL Server to excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, database-administration, sql-server-2019

I have scenario like this:
If I connect SQL Server view or stored procedure with excel i can get to see the data/table/pivot from SQL Server database, i can also refresh that excel, But if I share that excel with another user, that excel should not get refresh the data/view from the database, if someone other trying to refresh data Excel needs to get closed or need to show pop up with access denied.
Is this possible??
Can anyone help me to achieve solution.

Condition:
We are migrating SQL Server 2008 to 2019
For testing purpose we have developer edition of SQL Server 2019.
I want to give access to some higher authority to use that Excel, so we require user authentication as well.

Comment: You can use an integrated security connection and grant an access to only the domain user[s] you want.

Comment: Or don't save the password in the workbook. It will not refresh automatically anyway